# How to put auth around the documentation endpoint for swagger UI in flask-restplus?

Tags: flask, swagger, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I love flask restplus and swagger UI, the only thing that I haven't been able to figure out is how to put a custom auth decorator around the call to the documentation endpoint to prevent others from being able to see the documentation.

I thought it might be this section from the documentation

> If you need a custom UI, you can register a custom view function with
>   the documentation() decorator:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, apidoc

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@api.documentation
def custom_ui():
    return apidoc.ui_for(api)
```

but I did this and nothing seems to have happened.